# How to get a particular name from multiple IDs in a table?

Tags: sql

```
orderid  return id   status
a         a1        completed
b         a2        rejected
c         a3        initiated
d         a4        rejected
d         a5        completed
f         a6        rejected
g         a7        completed
a         a1        completed
```

output

```
a    a1      completed
```

I want the output where an order ID has more than 1 return id and both status are as 'completed'.

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation, if I understand correctly:

```
select orderid, returnid, max(status)
from t
group by orderid, returnid
having count(*) >= 2 and
       min(status) = max(status) and
       max(status) = 'completed';
```

You use the word "both", implying that there are exactly two rows, both of which have a status of `'completed'`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43001004bcc75c4924fd9d5f422b19b1) is a db<>fiddle (which happens to use MySQL but the code is all standard SQL).

Comment: what will the max function do here exactly?

Comment: with the above query query which you shared, I am getting 1 time 'completed' also.

Comment: @AdarshTiwari . . . Isn't that what you want?  This returns exactly what you specify in the question.

Comment: I want to get the id which is having at least 2 times 'completed' in the status.

Comment: @AdarshTiwari . . . I am just lost.  That is what this query does.  The results are exactly what your question specifies.  The SQL Fiddle illustrates all of this.  If you want at least 2 times, then use `>= 2`, which I just updated in the answer.